# Paste a paragraph into a nano editor

Tags: linux, shell, nano

I try to copy a paragraph from Word file  into a nano editor. When, I open the file  `nano file.txt`, I remark that the text is set into one long line.
Is there any option to automatically set the paragraph into several lines as in Word file?

I try `nano -w file.txt` but it does not work.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you.

Place the cursor at the beginning of each paragraph and press Ctrl+J.

It is used to justify/fill out a text paragraph. By default, it reflows text to match the editing window width and make your life easier.

See [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-how-to-edit-files-on-the-shell-with-nano) for more details.